# Microsoft Graph /drives/{drive-id}/root/search returns less results for "Application Auth token" than for "Delegated Auth"

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

I'm trying to find items in a drive with an Application Token Authorization with the Graph SDK. I do get some results on certain search queries.

However I get more results (on the same queries) with the MS Graph Explorer which is using Delegate Token Authorization.

How is that possible, shouldn't the application have Ability to access everything?

In both cases I'm searching on the same Drive

This is the API I'm using:
`/drives/{drive-id}/root/search(q='{search-text}')`

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the application can not access elements in personal drives unless they are under "Shared with everyone"